# Replace Line in config file

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I want to replace lines of the `Redmine` config file automatically. The config file looks like this:

```
# MySQL (default setup).
....
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:
  encoding: utf8

development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine_development
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:
  encoding: utf8
  ....
```

I only want to replace lines after the production section like password, database,...

How can I do that with `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your example file:

```
sed -r '/^production:/,/^$/{s/(\s*database:).*/\1newDB/;
        s/(\s*password:).*/\1newPWD/}' yourConfig
```

the above cmd will change "database" and "password" setting in "production" section to newDB and newPWD.

output:

```
...
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database:newDB
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:newPWD
  encoding: utf8

development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine_development
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:
  encoding: utf8
...
```